# The security token format does not conform to expected schema

Tags: docusignapi

I get the following response on Postman when making a GET request on

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{myclientidhere}/

The demo account integrator key was certified and moved to prod. I made the request in exactly the same way I did for the demo account using the new username, password and the integrator key details in prod. What could be going wrong here?

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <errorCode>INVALID_TOKEN_FORMAT</errorCode>
  <message>The security token format does not conform to expected schema.</message>
</errorDetails>
```

- Edit: 
  As suggested by DocuSign, am using na2 as our production account is residing in the na2 environment

My request follows:

```
GET

Endpoint
https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

Headers

Content-Type: application/json
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"x@x.com","Password":"xxxx","IntegratorKey":"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Have downloaded the request logs but the list of logs all return 200 OK except the one looking for a profile image which I do not have so makes sense to receive a 404 not found as there is no image to link to. I don't see any other issues.

Comment: Can you clarify what "myclientidhere" is?  i.e., is it simply a short number that represents your Account Id?  Or is it a GUID that represents something else?  Your Account Id will be different in Prod than in Demo.

Comment: It's an eight digit number like this 4xxxxxx3 and with no surrounding braces, I just did that like they do in the documentation.

Comment: & yes I am using the prod client id. I should be calling it account id.

Comment: Maybe try executing another type of request, using the same exact header info (username, password, integrator key)?  For example, the "Login" operation (GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information).  If that works, it'd suggest that there's something invalid about the "account Id" that you're including in your "Get Account" request URL.  If the "Login" request fails with the same error, i'd suggest there's probably something wrong with the request header values you're setting. In that case, try examining the full request trace (using Fiddler or something similar).

Comment: There might be a bug in the system currently, I just saw a note mentioning something about an error with the legacy header in JSON, can you try changing back to `application/xml` content type and configuring the auth header in xml:  `<DocuSignCredentials>
 <Username>usr</Username>
 <Password>pwd</Password>
 <IntegratorKey>IK</IntegratorKey>
</DocuSignCredentials>`

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: I've added an answer for the community, I think we also diagnosed Sheree that you had a backslash character in your password which we believe causes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

After working with the customer in the end we found the issue here was that they had the backslash `(\)` character in their password, which was being parsed as an escape sequence.

So basically the password was like:

```
a1b2@cd\%34
```

and the backslash was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran across the same problem. Apparently the `"` character is also disallowed in the password. Changed the password to exclude it and it now works fine.